# How do I modify this regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following format for emails on a page `<a href='mailto:xyz@xyz.com'>`
that I am trying to match with a regex

I am currently using this:

```
$pattern = '#a[^>]+href="mailto:([^"]+)"[^>]*?>#is';
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $email) {
    $emails[] = $email;
}
```

but it results in no match. `$emails` is `NULL`.

I am just learning regular expressions so please forgive the question!
Can someone explain why it doesn't work and suggest a change? Thanks

Comment: Well, when you **learn** something it is good when you write something **yourself**, from the scratch, not just modify the code you've found somewhere. Let's start solving the issue together, step by step, from the scratch (in case that you really want to *learn* something)

Comment: Please change the title of your question to be more meaningful to what you want to achieve before I change my mind and downvote just because of it.

Comment: a single quote is not the same as a double quote.

Comment: The HTML you posted has an `href` with single quotes whereas the regular expression uses double quotes. *(Insert obligatory rant about [parsing HTML with regex here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))*

Comment: Use DOM and this XPath: `//a/@href[starts-with(., 'mailto:')]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you in your example use single qoutes `'` whereas in the regex it's looking for double quotes `"`.

Changing your pattern to:

```
$pattern = '#a[^>]+href=\'mailto:([^\']+)\'[^>]*?>#is';
```

Would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the support for double an single quotes as @Linus-Kleen and @thetaiko said:

```
$pattern = '#a[^>]+href=[\'"]mailto:([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*?>#is';
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex works, but you don't check for both ' (single quote) and " (double quote) so that

```
<a href='mailto:xyz@xyz.com'>
```

Will not get matched, but

```
<a href="mailto:xyz@xyz.com">
```

will.

Simply changing the regex to

```
'#a[^>]+href=[\'"]+mailto:([^"]+)[\'"]+[^>]*?>#is'
```

will do the trick!